# Protractor How to call a key having multiple suite values from properties file using npm properties reader

Tags: javascript, node.js, properties, npm, protractor

I had a requirement where i need to store some data outside **conf.js** file.

so i had installed **properties-reader** node module but i'm facing some problems while accessing some key values.
Below are my properties file and conf.js file

**config.properties file**

```
[main]
browserName = chrome
shardTestFiles = true
maxInstances = 4
suites = ../specs/folder1/*.js
```

**conf.js file**

```
var PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');
var properties = PropertiesReader('config.properties');
 multiCapabilities: [
        {
            'browserName': properties.get('main.browserName'),
            shardTestFiles: properties.get('main.shardTestFiles'),
            maxInstances: properties.get('main.maxInstances'),
        },
suites: {
         Suite : [properties.get('main.suites')],
        },
```

with above configuration i'm able execute all specs in folder1.
but when i try to add one more folder as below.

**config.properties file**

```
[main]
browserName = chrome
shardTestFiles = true
maxInstances = 4
suites = ../specs/folder1/*.js,../specs/folder2/*.js
```

I'm getting below error.

```
BEFORE LAUNCH
WARNING - pattern ../specs/folder1/*.js,../specs/folder2/*.js did not match any files.
```

what is the syntax to store multiple folder paths in **.properties** file so that i can call them in my conf.js file

Comment: Did you try this? 
To read more than one file, chain calls to the .append() method:

properties.append('/another.file').append('/yet/another.file');

Comment: You create different files for different suite.

Comment: i cannot create different files, my main target is to reduce no of files hence i'm thinking of only one config.properties file and one conf.js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small tricky error here. Each suite defined under `suites` should be an array of paths of specs.

`[properties.get('main.suites')]` - This will just return a string and not an array

You need to split the test paths to form an array to make this work

```
var PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');
var properties = PropertiesReader('config.properties');
suites: {
   Suite: properties.get('main.suites').split(","),
   },
```

Comment: Thank You Aditya Reddy for the suggestion, it worked, You just saved my Day :)

Comment: @sid ... glad that it helped :)